# How to change value in only one textformfield flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, counter

I am using in the function Counter in a row. But when I click on increment or decrement, I am changing the data in two fields at the same time. I understand that in CounterCubit I have only one value declared and it passes twice to the same function and therefore it changes. Tell me how to correctly separate the values ​​​​for each field so that the value does not change in two fields at the same time, but only in one corresponding one?

**filter dialog**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Dialog(
        insetPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 24, right: 24),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24))),
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(21, 38, 21, 24),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                 const PriceCounter(title: 'From'),
              ]
```

**price counter**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CounterCubit cubit = BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context);

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
              builder: (context, state) => InputField(
                  price: state.countValue.toString(),
                  textStyle: constants.Styles.normalBookTextStyleWhite),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => cubit.increment(),
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.plus),
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 24),
                Text(title, style: constants.Styles.smallLtStdTextStyleWhite),
                const SizedBox(width: 24),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => cubit.decrement(),
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.minus),
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // const SizedBox(width: 24),
        Column(
          children: [
            BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
              builder: (context, state) => InputField(
                  price: state.countValue.toString(),
                  textStyle: constants.Styles.normalBookTextStyleWhite),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => cubit.increment(),
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.plus),
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 24),
                Text(title, style: constants.Styles.smallLtStdTextStyleWhite),
                const SizedBox(width: 24),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => cubit.decrement(),
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.minus),
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                ),
```

**input field**

```
class InputField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String price;
  final TextStyle textStyle;

  const InputField({Key? key, required this.price, required this.textStyle})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InputField> createState() => _InputField();
}

class _InputField extends State<InputField> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _priceController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _priceController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
        width: 90,
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            controller: _priceController..text = '€${widget.price} KWh',
            style: widget.textStyle,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

**counter state**

```
class CounterState {
  final double countValue;
  const CounterState({required this.countValue});
}
```

**counter cubit**

```
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState> {
  CounterCubit() : super(const CounterState(countValue: 0.13));

  void increment() => emit(CounterState(countValue: state.countValue + 0.01));

  void decrement() => emit(CounterState(countValue: state.countValue - 0.01));
}
```

**Here is the result**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the exactly same state to both inputs:

```dart
state.countValue
```

Why you not just create another state to the other input field?

```dart
state.firstCountValue
state.secondCountValue
```